# Attendance system to prevent freeloaders from attending my institute

Tags: software-development, face-recognition

I am part of a mid-sized coaching institute in India, with branches spread across different regions. 
Typically we have a batch size of 30, and the course length is around 3 months.

Recently we have been noticing that a lot of freeloaders, who haven't registered for our courses, come along with their friends.

Some of the constraints are:

1. Once a student has registered for a course, he can attend the classes for the next 2 years.
2. Limited manpower - We can just allot one guy to each branch for the branch administration. On weekends, several batches run simultaneously at each branch. So, manual checking of I-cards is out of the option.

Budget is not a constraint here.

We are looking for a robust system, which helps us in preventing the freeloaders from coming.

**Note**: we do have the eMail ID of each registered student.

Comment: Yes. We have the email ID as well as the phone number of each registered student. And their photos too, in case you want to suggest face recognition system.

Comment: Well there is a company here in the states offering to implant RFID chips in their workers for "convenience" ....

Answer (score 2):

Since you do have the eMail Id of each registered student, you could eMail each of them some type of UNIQUE token. And ask them to somehow visualize that token during the courses (wear it as some type of badge, or put it somewhere on their desk). Up to you to decide how often the tokens should be renewed (= send a new eMail with an updated token).

With that, all that's left is to validate those tokens with some list of those tokens that got emailed, whenever the time is right to do so.

Obviously, these are the unrigistered users that will get caught:

- those who do not have a token.
- those who have an invalid token (not on the list).
- tokens that are used by multiple students.

***Easy, no***?

Ps: since budget is not a constraint, I'd be happy to become the token validator ...

Comment: With budget not being a constraint, that token could be made a QR-Code (or NFC token) and a barrier put at the door, like in airports, with a QR/NFC reader. Only valid QR codes / NFC tokens are accepted, and even those only once per hour (or another interval; thinking of leaving the room for toilet or other breaks, or switching rooms, or whatever other demands there could be). (PS: Sorry for spoiling your "personal validator idea" that way, Pierre #D)

Comment: @Izzy yes I do agree with you (and I could add a dozen of variations of using such QR-codes). But at its core, I think the clue will be that you need to have some mechanism in place to exchange some type of token ... most straight forward seems to me to just use eMail (to **K**eep **I**t **S**uper **S**imple, aka KISS, n'est çe pas?) ...

Comment: Sure, no contradiction: Encode the email address to QR/NFC. The "door lock" reads the token/QR-Code, extracts the EMail, verifies it against a database, and acts accordingly. // Now we've presented a solution, but have been pretty much off-topic: Where to download the application, what are our personal experiences with it, …? =:-0

Comment: @Izzy I agree (also) ... And I'm now waiting for the approved budget to be assigned ... (in other words: hire us and we'll tell you ...). Or at least some kind of token-of-appreciation, such as what is suggested [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).